# Array list not obtaining smallest age

Tags: arraylist, output

I've setup 2 different array lists that coincide and I have code to find the biggest age and smallest age, However my youngest age isn't outputting. I am getting the biggest age as outputted

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Database1{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> age = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a first name");
        String inputName = in.nextLine();
        if(inputName.contains("done")){
            break;
        }
        
        name.add(inputName);
        System.out.println("Please enter an age");
        age.add(in.nextInt());
        in.nextLine();
        count++;
    }
    int smallest = age.get(0);
    int biggest = age.get(0);
    String youngestName = "" ;
    String oldestName = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < age.size(); i++) {
        if(age.get(i) > biggest){
            biggest = age.get(i);
            oldestName = name.get(i);
            
        }if (age.get(i) < smallest){
            smallest = age.get(i);
            youngestName = name.get(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The oldest person was " + oldestName);
    System.out.println("The youngest person was " + youngestName);
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(age);
}
```

}
I am receiving this as an output

The oldest person was john

The youngest person was

[Luke, Chris, Neal, john]

[18, 19, 44, 66]

Answer (score 0):

Modify to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> age = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();

    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a first name");
        String inputName = in.nextLine();
        if(inputName.contains("done")){
            break;
        }

        name.add(inputName);
        System.out.println("Please enter an age");
        age.add(in.nextInt());
        in.nextLine();
        count++;
    }
    int smallest = age.get(0);
    int biggest = age.get(0);
    String youngestName = name.get(0); ;
    String oldestName = name.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < age.size(); i++) {
        if(age.get(i) > biggest){
            biggest = age.get(i);
            oldestName = name.get(i);

        } else if (age.get(i) < smallest){
            smallest = age.get(i);
            youngestName = name.get(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The oldest person was " + oldestName);
    System.out.println("The youngest person was " + youngestName);
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(age);
}
```